# docker-compose: How to implement startup scripts in containers?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have several worker node.js scripts that I'm planning to containerize. And just before the whole set of worker containers starts I need to run several "startup" scripts (JS also) - only one time for initialization (fill database with values, etc). How can I achieve this with docker-compose?

I don't want to containerize these startup scripts in worker container, maybe I should create separate containers for them? But how can I make them run only once BEFORE workers and then shut down?

Comment: " how can I make them run only once...?" a common solution here is to create some sort of flag file indicating that the scripts has already run, and use the existence of that file to determine whether or not to run the script when the container starts.

Comment: (You can see an example of that in e.g. the official postgres image, [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/14/bullseye/docker-entrypoint.sh#L228).)

Comment: You could use a Makefile/script to start the containers via compose, then run anything else after each are up

Comment: @larsks yes but I don't want to include the script itself in the worker container

Comment: @OneCricketeer please explain it to me, what did you mean?

Comment: Like I said, write a script.... `docker-compose up ; sleep 10; node scripts/populate-db.js localhost:PORT/database`, or do the same in `package.json`. Dont do it all in containers. Or, if you do, then see reference like Postgres/MySQL containers already do to import data from a volume mount

Comment: @OneCricketeer thank you! If I don't do it in containers how can I run it in for example AWS cloud?